# Installing R on Linux: configure: WARNING: you cannot build PDF versions of the R manuals

Tags: r, pdf, installation, debian

While configuring R on Debian GNU/Linux 8.8 (jessie) I am getting the warning above. Any ideas which package should be installed to solve the issue and have the manuals build as PDF?

Comment: Firing from the hip here. Do you have LaTeX installed?

Comment: No LaTeX installed, I'll try installing the texlive package then, even though it looks a bit overkill with all the packages it brings

Comment: Indeed installing LaTeX helps but there is now a complain about missing sty files: configure: WARNING: neither inconsolata.sty nor zi4.sty found: PDF vignettes and package manuals will not be rendered optimally

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A possible solution is to install LaTeX:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive
```

This enables production of PDF but leaves a warning on missing sty files open:

```
configure: WARNING: neither inconsolata.sty nor zi4.sty found: PDF vignettes and package manuals will not be rendered optimally
```

To solve the issue, install the extra fonts package to texlive

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-extra
```

Comment: Perhaps installing https://www.ctan.org/pkg/inconsolata?lang=en would help?

Comment: Searching packages I've found it in texlive-fonts-extra, insatlling it solves the issue, thanks

Comment: @a1an Although I have installed `texlive` but this warning arises for me.

Comment: @alhelal You do not have to install just `texlive` but the package with extra fonts `texlive-fonts-extra`

Answer (score 3):

On Fedora:

`sudo dnf install texlive-inconsolata`

This will install the [inconsolata font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inconsolata), which is the font that R uses for the manual. See [Rd.sty](https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/share/texmf/tex/latex/Rd.sty).